Can debit cards with the Maestro logo be used in ATMs in Taiwan?
Debit cards with the Maestro logo work very well in Japan, they can be used at every ATM in a 7/11. Actually, I found (on YT) that most ATMs in Taiwan come along with a Cirrus label. Cirrus seems to be the network that Mastercard is operating, therefore they should actually work with Maestro cards, but I am not sure.
Furthermore, Mastercard wants to withdraw its commitment with the money cards issued by the German Sparkasse, but cards usually work with Maestro until the validity of the card ends.
So can these cards be used in Taiwan's ATMs ?

Maestro is a MasterCard brand, so all ATMs (incl. those in Taiwan) that accept MasterCard cards should accept Maestro cards as well. MasterCard provides only one ATM locator for all types of their cards.
That being said, the Maestro card brand is discontinued in Europe (not only in the German Sparkasse), with no more cards being issued after July 1, 2023. Existing European Maestro cards should work at least until 2027, but their acceptance might be spotty (source). Other sources mention that Maestro cards have high fees for cash withdrawals abroad (I won't post a link, since it's not an authoritative source, just a forum).
Conclusion: Your Maestro card will probably work in Taiwan, but don't let it be your only card. Always bring at least two cards, from different banks and different card companies (ideally one from the Visa family and another from the MasterCard one).

Yep, for some reason Maestro cards have always been a mess, and it's a good thing they're phasing them out, this should hopefully bring more clarity and uniformity.

Thanks for the answer. How safe is the statement "Your Maestro card will probably work in Taiwan" ? As additional card I only have VISA, and I already experienced problems with VISA upon money withdrawal, but not with Maestro (when VISA failed work, Maestro worked though).

@FredericThomas I've never been to Taiwan, but I couldn't find any evidence of Maestro cards not working there. I can't see why a VISA might be a problem either. Have you already had problems with it in Taiwan? The VISA ATM locator lists plenty of ATMs on the island...

In Taiwan no. Haven't been there yet. But in South Korea yes. Maestro works, VISA less upon withdrawing money.

@FredericThomas Is your Maestro card issued by a european bank? If yes, I'd get a MasterCard instead, just to be on the safe side.
